# AppMessage from Android doesnt seem to reach the Pebble watch app

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I am making a pebble watch app which downloads an image using [netdownload.c from pebble-faces](https://github.com/pebble-examples/pebble-faces/blob/master/src/netdownload.c). Because netdownload.c registers appmessage handlers in initialization routine and I never call de-init, I thought that any message that I send from my Android app will reach the netdownload_receive() function. But this doesnt happen although the image download is successful. I think the code should print the log from this line in netdownload.com:

```
APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_WARNING, "Unknown key in dict: %lu", tuple->key);
```

but it never does. Am I missing something? How do I get the message to watch app? Do I have to register appmessage routines again in my watch app even if netdownload is registering them?

Comment: You should see this message if you send other messages from your JavaScript. Can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

You mention that a log event should fire when an AppMessage comes in on the watch and that this doesn't happen, which leads to the question: are you sure that the AppMessage is received by the watch in the first place? You mentioned an Android app, so I'm going to assume you're using PebbleKit Android and not PebbleKit.js. In this case, you could try implementing a [PebbleNackReceiver](http://developer.getpebble.com/docs/android/com/getpebble/android/kit/PebbleKit.PebbleNackReceiver) and check whether the message you send from the phone gets NACK'ed and if yes, what the result code is. The result code will tell you what went wrong.